# howto present timestamp in readable format on mails sent from wso2das event publisher

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Currently i'm using WSO2DAS event publisher to send mail notifications. My problem is that i want to present the value of the event timestamps in a readable format (UTC format maybe) but currently mails are sent with the timestamp in UNIX format. Is there any special attribute holding a textual representation of the event timestamp or any function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use currentTimestamp() function for that. It gives the timestamp in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format.

As an example

```
from inputStream
select time:currentTimestamp() as outputTime
insert into outputStream
```

Using above queries you can get a human readable timestamp in the mail body.

For more time related functions refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Siddhi+Extensions#SiddhiExtensions-time

Comment: I will hold your solution as a last resource. But it seems counterproductive for me having to create an execution plan and a second event stream just to be able to print the event timestamp in a readable format. Is there no solution to your acknowledge provided by the event publisher itself? May be mapping?

Comment: Sorry AFAIK that is not possible. You may have to create an execution plan for the conversion process.

Comment: I read the documentation for time:currentTimestamp() and it renders the current timestamp not an event timestamp. So basically the answer is wrong